# I'm having trouble trying to export the data from an object in Flutter using get_it

Tags: flutter, scope, global-variables, local-variables, get-it

Basically, I'm able to send user locations to an API, and I want that upon sending, I can capture this location and make it global throughout my project, so that I can create a widget to display the location. I'm using get_it and it always returns:

Bad state: GetIt ObjectFactory with type UserLocation is not registered inside GetIt

mycode

```
final GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator(double latitude, double longitude, String registeredAt){
    locator.registerSingleton<UserLocation>(UserLocation
       latitude: latitude,
       longitude: longitude,
       registeredAt: registeredAt

));

}


  class SendLocationController {

   Future<Void> sendLocationToApi(LocationDto apiData) async {

   //api data is ok, it is sending

   setupLocator(apiData.latitude,apiData.longitude, apiData.registeredAt)
   UserLocation locationOnSend = locator<UserLocation>();

}
   

}

Widget buildUserLocation(){
UserLocation locationOnSend = locator<UserLocation>();
//rest of widget
}
```

Am I using get_it incorrectly?

How do I create an object within an asynchronous function, make it global, and use it throughout my project, specifically to build a widget with this data? Thank you, folks